# Setting DNS on a VPS

Tags: dns, centos

I am pretty new to server administration so I am looking for some help with setting up my DNS correctly and generally expanding my knowledge around the area. I have a domain name registered with Godaddy from a while back. I have recently setup a VPS with a separate company and I wish to point my Godaddy registered domain to my new server.

From what I've read, I can either point my Zone file's A record to my new server IP, or I can point my current Godaddy Nameservers to my new server (and this would use my new server's DNS? - I'm assuming this would require more work on my VPS).
Can anyone confirm this for me, and possibly explain why one is preferred over the other and/ or what the explicit differences are?

I am running CentOs 5.8.

Thanks for any tips, advice, nudges in the right direction.

Comment: If you keep your current Go Daddy and just point your A record to your server the DNS is managed off the server.  The benefit is that if your server goes down DNS is still up and your email
(if hosted at a location not on your server) will still be up.  The draw back is DNS is not hosted on the server so you are managing your domain from two locations.

Comment: If you setup custom nameservers and host your DNS on the server you are managing everything in one place and your nameservers would be set to something like ns1.YOURDOMAIN.COM and ns2.YOURDOMAIN.COM.  The downside if that if the server is offline the domain's DNS is down and email is down as well, even if it is hosted on another server.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response Mike. That's cleared it up for me!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look of this [Howto](http://www.ehowstuff.com/how-to-setup-private-dns-with-bind9-chroot-on-centos-6-2-vps/) on how to Setup Private DNS With Bind9 Chroot on CentOS 6.2 VPS. Not much different on the bind configuration for CentOS 5.x and CentOS 6.x. The following configuration has been enabled :

1. forwarding named server
2. Bind chroot named service
3. Master(ns1)/Salve (ns2) server. Slave is allowed to download master's zoned files.